# calculated textbox value can be changed/recalculated while a combobox value is changed in access

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

I have made a small database, I want to recalculate the "Balance_textbox" value when I change the date in "combobox" , because calculation in the textbox is based on the selected value of combobox. Both controls are on the same form

I am using MS Access 2007, combobox has a single column

combobox has dates , which are being fetched by the "Day" field of the table "sales" and textbox is calculating total balance of the records, based dates of the combobox

below is the Control source of the Balance_textbox

```
=DSum("[Sale]-[Expense]","Sales",
    " [Day] BETWEEN Forms![Main Form]![Combo40] 
    AND Forms![Main Form]![Combo42] ")-DSum("[Cashwithdraw]","Sales"," [Day] 
    BETWEEN Forms![Main Form]![Combo40] AND Forms![Main Form]![Combo42] ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the calling the `recalc` method for the form in the AfterUpdate event for the combobox?

It might look something like this

```
Forms![Main Form].recalc
```

or

```
  Me.Recalc
```

Comment: Recalc or Requery method is not working, I have tried many times to Requery "Balance_text box" and also Requery form. Totally stuck..  Any other idea will be appreciated